# Applying math.dist() to pandas dataframe in a fast way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (df):

```
Name            Point1                  Point2
name1     '[x_coord, y_coord]'     '[x_coord, y_coord]'
name2     '[x_coord, y_coord]'     '[x_coord, y_coord]'
name3     '[x_coord, y_coord]'     '[x_coord, y_coord]'
etc...
```

I want to add a new column 'Distance' which applies the following to all rows:
`math.dist(ast.literal_eval(df['Point1']), ast.literal_eval(df['Point2']))`.

However, this does not work:

```
df['Distance'] = math.dist(ast.literal_eval(df['Point1']), ast.literal_eval(df['Point2']))
```

The loop below works, but it is taking way too long because I have millions of rows:

```
dist_list = [math.dist(ast.literal_eval(row[2]), ast.literal_eval(row[3])) for row in df.itertuples()]
```

What I am looking for here is something that will **do this to all rows at once, because looping takes too long**. Similar to what happens if we want to multiply all rows by an integer 'n', no need to loop, just do `df['new_col'] = df['old_col'] * n`

Another thing I tried and is also taking too long was to create a function and call with apply and lambda, like this:

```
def get_dist(p1: str, p2: str):
    return math.dist(ast.literal_eval(p1), ast.literal_eval(p2))

df['Distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_dist(x['Point1'], x['Point2']), axis=1)
```

Is there a faster way to get the result I want?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I also have 4 other columns with the point coordinates in float, not string (`Xcoord_point1, Ycoord_point1, Xcoord_point2, Ycoord_point2`) if it helps somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PS: I also have 4 other columns with the point coordinates in float, not string (Xcoord_point1, Ycoord_point1, Xcoord_point2, Ycoord_point2) if it helps somehow.

That helps - use NumPy:

```py
import numpy as np

df["Distance"] = np.sqrt(
    (df["Xcoord_point1"].values - df["Xcoord_point2"].values) ** 2
    + (df["Ycoord_point1"].values - df["Ycoord_point2"].values) ** 2
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It never occurred to me to use the formula of math.dist on its own, it is indeed a thousand times faster :)